# Issues with Artifactory and NGINX proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, artifactory

I'm having issues with nginx and proxy pass. I have setup an instance of JFrog Artifactory and pointed my domain to it successfully; however the port is still appearing in the "URL to file" ([the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/618Pv.png)). Here is my nginx config

```
server {
  
server_name repo.hyperiamc.com;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
    set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
}
## Application specific logs
rewrite ^/$ /ui/ redirect;
rewrite ^/ui$ /ui/ redirect;
chunked_transfer_encoding on;
client_max_body_size 0;
location / {
    proxy_read_timeout  2400s;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass          http://x.x.x.x:8082;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries    1;
    proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
        proxy_pass    http://x.x.x.x:8081;
    }
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/repo.hyperiamc.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/repo.hyperiamc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot }
```

Visiting the site the URL works, it appears that it's only the URL to file. I have set my Base URL inside of artifactory to match that of the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to the header value we are setting up in the config. Change the line.
From: proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;

TO:     proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;

Hope this helps.